# How to avoid CopyTask and MoveTask phing build exception on not existing file

Tags: php, xml, build, phing

I'm creating build file for phing. The problem is that it must move a file which may not exist. If it doesn't I get `BuildException` "Could not find file ... to copy".

In the Ant there was a property `failonerror` which ignored the errors of move and copy tasks, but there is no similar property for phing move and copy tasks.

Move phing code:

```
<move file="no_such_file.txt" tofile="other_path.txt" overwrite="true" />
```

Is there any built in functionality to catch the errors using phing build? Or maybe it's possible to check on file existence before moving?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have avoided the problem using such move task:

```
<move todir="${dir}" overwrite="true">
    <mapper type="glob" from="no_such_file.txt" to="other_path.txt"/>
    <fileset dir="${dir}" />
</move>
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a ticket (see http://phing.info/trac/ticket/582) to add a haltonerror attribute to the copy/move tasks.

Comment: Thank you! Seems it has been fixed recently.